# what is the alternate method for driver.findelements("").get(i) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Let's say,

```
i=2
@driver.find_elements("...").get(i).click
```

[image]

How to define similar method in ruby; any tweak on the same?

Comment: Did you try `$driver.find_elements("...")[i].click`?

Comment: not yet; let me try :) thanks!

Comment: find_elements returns array, So you can't use, array object doesn't have get() method, So use [index], driver.find_elements[2].click

Comment: My another question is, why do you choose to use Ruby binding directly? You could use WATIR which is nice wrapper around Ruby Binding.

Comment: Yes, you could, I answered, You could use find_elements(id: 'something')[2], you can't use `get(i)` because array object doesn't have get() function.

Comment: Can you post some html code? that would help me to figure out the problem.

Comment: That link tag is not completely visible, Can you post that link  tag completely because I could able to locate using link text.

Comment: Update the answer below, please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to click that link

`get` method is not available for array, you can take first element by `first` and last element by `last` and if you want any other elements you could use [i]

```
@driver.find_elements("...")[i].click
```

Comment: @PrashanthSams you can't use `get()` function for array, array doesn't have that function, if you want to use you could `first` `last` or to take a particular element you could use [4]!

Comment: @PrashanthSams Updated, you could check it now.

Comment: @PrashanthSams you can't call find_element()[2], you can call find_elements()[2], find_element doesn't return array, so your suggested one is wrong.

Comment: @PrashanthSams Okay.